# Question about condition check in linklist

Tags: c

If head is a struct type pointer, pointing to the first node in link list then what does while(head) means? Does While loop runs till the head is not equal to NULL? Also what does if(!head) means while checking the condition

Comment: `while(head)` means `while(head != NULL)`. In a boolean expression, `0` is `false` and all other values are `true`.

Comment: and `if(!head)` is like `if (head == NULL)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If head is a struct type pointer, pointing to the first node in link list then what does while(head) means?

to have

> ```
> while(head)
> ```

is like to have

```
while(head != NULL)
```

> Does While loop runs till the head is not equal to NULL?

yes (supposing there is nothing allowing to go out of the loop in its body)

> Also what does if(!head) means while checking the condition

to have

> ```
>  if(!head)
> ```

is like to have

```
if(head == NULL)
```